# Magento2 Tax exemption for client/product combination

Tags: magento2, tax

I need to setup exemptions only on certain products assigned to certain customers.

For example customer A and customer B are both in the same class as a general rule however customer A is tax exempt on product 1 but pays taxes on product 2 (which are also both in the same product class) while customer B pays taxes on both products.

How do I assign 0% tax on product 1 for customer A?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exempting specific customer groups from tax on specific products would require unique product tax classes if you're only working within the constraints of Magento's tax rules. There isn't a way to create multiple tax rules to handle this logic with the same product tax class.

If you're planning to do this for many products, it might be worthwhile to build a custom module that provides a way to select exempt customer groups when editing individual products. You could then override Magento's tax calculations and exempt from tax programatically.

Comment: I was thinking about a CSV field in the customer profile where I can setup the item numbers on which to exempt taxes and override tax calculation if the product number are present in the EAV field... I'm still learning magento 2 and I'm having to start from the very basics to achieve that...